# Facebook Graph API to fetch Pages that I may create content

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

1) With Graph API, I may manage to fetch Pages (`https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/accounts`) & Groups (`https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/groups`) that I'm administer so I may post new content on these pages & groups.

But I don't know there's any solution to fetch Pages I liked, Groups I joined, then detect if I have permission to publish new content on these Pages & Groups?

2) Furthermore, I may fetch all liked things from API (`https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/likes`); so there's any quick solution to detect & get all access tokens of Pages & Groups in this `likes` list? Because this list returns  a set of (`name`, `id`) only, not contain permission & type of thing.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

- User `/me/accounts` to get all Pages you manage
- User `/me/likes` to get all Pages you like
- For each Page you like, check if there is an entry in `/me/accounts` - in other words, compare those datasets

About groups: You can only get groups you manage anyway, with the `/me/groups` endpoint. There is no way to get all groups.

Btw, if you want to get more fields than just id and name in the response, you have to use the `fields` parameter. Check out the docs about that, and about the existing fields.

**Just to be clear: You cannot post to Groups or Pages you don´t own/manage.**

Comment: yes, I mean Groups I joined, Pages I have permission to post. May tell me there's any field in endpoint `likes` indicates that a node is group, page or user? thanks

Comment: you can only get pages with the likes endpoints, not groups or users...you cannot like users or groups. please don´t try to spam on facebook, the api is there to post on YOUR groups and YOUR pages.